# How to get a specific chunk from a delayed dask array?

Tags: python, arrays, iterator, dask

Suppose I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import dask

arr_x = list(range(0,100))
arr_y = list(range(0,100))
arr = np.stack([arr_x,arr_y])
arr = arr.T
```

Then I want to transform it in a delayed dask array:

```
arr = da.from_array(arr,chunks = (3,2))
data = arr.to_delayed()
```

Which has the following format:

```
[[Delayed(('array-fa3499f6a402676a68a198bef8016ec4', 0, 0))]
 [Delayed(('array-fa3499f6a402676a68a198bef8016ec4', 1, 0))]
 [Delayed(('array-fa3499f6a402676a68a198bef8016ec4', 2, 0))]

...
 [Delayed(('array-fa3499f6a402676a68a198bef8016ec4', 31, 0))]
 [Delayed(('array-fa3499f6a402676a68a198bef8016ec4', 32, 0))]
 [Delayed(('array-fa3499f6a402676a68a198bef8016ec4', 33, 0))]]
```

Now I want to get a specific chunk:

```
chunk = da.from_delayed(data[1], shape=(3,2))
print(chunk.compute())
```

However, I get the following error:

```
dsk = {(name,) + (0,) * len(shape): value.key}

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'key'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dask.array.Array.to_delayed()` returns a list of lists for a 2-D array. You need to slice all the way down to a delayed object to pass it to from_delayed()

```
In [5]: chunk = da.from_delayed(data[1][0], shape=(3,2), dtype=arr.dtype)

In [6]: chunk.compute()
Out[6]:
array([[3, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 5]])
```

This could also be written as

```
In [11]: arr.blocks[1, 0].compute()
Out[11]:
array([[3, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 5]])
```